DOTween OnComplete did not execute the command when looping
I have a code to move a model to a specific location and then play an animation
using DG.Tweening;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class stegamove : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator animator;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _stega;
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _stega.DOMove(new Vector3(-2.05f, -0.56f, -3.06f), 3).SetEase(Ease.InSine).OnComplete(() =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Here");
            animator.Play("Armature|Stegasaurus_Stomp");
        });
        }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}

This works fine and the action is performed correctly. However, if I want to loop the animation and change the line
_stega.DOMove(new Vector3(-2.05f, -0.56f, -3.06f), 3).SetEase(Ease.InSine).OnComplete(() =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Here");
            animator.Play("Armature|Stegasaurus_Stomp");
        });

to
_stega.DOMove(new Vector3(-2.05f, -0.56f, -3.06f), 3).SetEase(Ease.InSine).OnComplete(() =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Here");
            animator.Play("Armature|Stegasaurus_Stomp");
        }).SetLoops(-1,LoopType.Restart);

the object simply moves back to the initial position without playing the animation.
How do I fix this?

You need to use OnStepComplete. Read more about it here
